# UI Bootstrap Datepicker Popup date format

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using a UI Bootstrap Datepicker Popup, and I would like to use a custom date format. My rest service sends me dates with 'dd/MM/yyyy' format.
I want to use this format but it when changing the model value, the date picker is not update. I defined `uib-datepicker-popup="dd/MM/yyyy"` but does not seem to work.

Plunker : https://plnkr.co/edit/SfSXmeL0ue0yef1yTKMO?p=preview

```js
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('DatepickerPopupDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.today = function() {
    $scope.dt = '02/01/2017';
  };

  $scope.clear = function() {
    $scope.dt = null;
  };

  $scope.dateOptions = {
    formatYear: 'yy',
    startingDay: 1
  };

  $scope.open1 = function() {
    $scope.popup1.opened = true;
  };

  $scope.popup1 = {
    opened: false
  };
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

<style>
  .full button span {
    background-color: limegreen;
    border-radius: 32px;
    color: black;
  }
  .partially button span {
    background-color: orange;
    border-radius: 32px;
    color: black;
  }
</style>
<div ng-controller="DatepickerPopupDemoCtrl">
    <pre>Selected date is: <em>{{dt | date:'fullDate' }}</em></pre>

    <h4>Popup</h4>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <p class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="dd/MM/yyyy" ng-model="dt" is-open="popup1.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" alt-input-formats="altInputFormats" />
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open1()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
          </span>
        </p>
      </div>


    </div>

    <hr />
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" ng-click="today()">Today</button>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

On the plunker:
- Click "today", makes `$scope.dt = '02/01/2017'`
- Open the date picker popup, it initialized on February the 1st instead of January the 2nd

Comment: You are required to post a minimal example of the problem code and markup here, not your plunker which can change or disappear tomorrow helping no one in the future: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I added a snippet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some research, I think I was looking for a directive to add custom parser and formatter :

```
.directive('dateFormatter', [
    function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
              ngModel.$parsers.push(function(data) {
                return moment(data).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
              });

              ngModel.$formatters.push(function(data) {
                return moment(data, 'DD/MM/YYYY').toDate()
              });
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

Updated plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/oi1EtcDmzpzyyKmXvhqz?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

UI Bootstrap datepicker exposes the date parser it uses internally as a service. Inject the `uibDateParser` service into your controller and use the parse function to wrangle your dates into the correct format:

```
function ($scope, uibDateParser) {
  $scope.today = function() {
    $scope.dt = uibDateParser.parse('02/01/2017', 'dd/MM/yyyy');
  };
...
}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/u5GRT5QOjdT61zZ36fmE?p=preview

Comment: In fact, I'm receiving this date through a rest service, so I don't want to make a new Date(). My data looks like {begin:"01/02/2017",end:"02/02/2017"}

Comment: I was looking for a way to tell the datepicker which format it should use to parse dates. Isn't that possible?

Comment: Actually that is possible...https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/dateparser

Comment: Parsing in my model doesn't look like a good solution to me. If my dto contains a lot of dates, I will need to parse all of them individually. I think I found a better solution using a directive (see my accepted answer).